# Add include directory to scons

Tags: include, scons

I have a project which has been checked out of Subversion and uses Scons for building.  However, I have a library installed on my computer which Scons doesn't detect - it just says that the include file can't be found.  Is there any way that I can direct Scons to the library location without altering the Sconscript file at all (because I don't want to have to deal with conflicts every time I update) - e.g. add a command line option that it will detect before searching for the include file?  I can't even see all the available options because it doesn't respond to the *--help* option before it searches for the include files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, after some more googling, I found that there is a way to do it.  *gcc* has a number of default directories that it searches (which I already knew - I just didn't know what they were defined as).  The simplest way to do what I was after is to add the directories to these environment variables.  The one that I needed was

```
$CPATH
```

This sets the path where gcc searches for its include files.  Setting this to the directory I needed solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

you can set env["CPPPATH"], but I hope there's an easier way...

Answer (score 1):

SCons has a concept of repositories - directories to look for source and target files. These can be specified on command line.

```
-Y REPOSITORY, --repository=REPOSITORY, --srcdir=REPOSITORY
                            Search REPOSITORY for source and target files.
```

To get to help of SCons itself, use `-H` option.

Answer (score -2):

no you can't, unless the developer of the scons script explicitly adds support for it.